# DL380 G10 - P816 controller - Extending LD produces error about max size, even though there is more space in the Array

Tags: storage, hardware-raid, hp-smart-array

Array A on this DL380 G10 consists of 9 1.9TB drives in a RAID 5 config.

It reports unused space of 619995 MB.

There are two logical drives, LD 1 with 13.55 TB (14,000,000 MB), and LD 3 with 97.66 GB (100,000 MB).

I wanted to extend LD 1 to use some of the 619995 MB before adding another drive to Array A.  I came up with 598490 MB, and tried to extend the drive using the command "ctrl slot=0 ld 1 modify size=14598490".

I got the following error:
Error: "size=14598490" is not a valid option for logicaldrive 1

Available options are:
Max: 14551104 (Units in MB)
Min: 14000000 (Units in MB)
MaxMBR: Max. for MBR Partition Table (2097152 MB = 2 TB)

Huh?  The Min makes sense, that's the current size of the drive, but I can't figure out why my Max size is 14551104.

Can someone help me figure out what limit I have run into?

I also thought I set up everything with GPT so I don't understand the bit about MaxMBR, or is that just boiler-plate error stuff.

If I've hit the limit on the size of LD 1, then there's no point adding another drive to the array, I might as well start a new array and create LD 4 on it.

I should add that Array B consists of 2 1.6TB drives in a RAID 1 configuration and LD 2 takes up all its space.

Thanks, Martin

**Additional information**

**esxcli ssacli cmd -q "ctrl all show config"**

HPE Smart Array P816i-a SR Gen10 in Slot 0 (Embedded)

Encryption is enabled for this controller. Data stored on physical drives that
are exposed to the OS will not be encrypted.

(sn: PEYHD0BRHAM071)

Internal Drive Cage at Port 1I, Box 3, OK

Internal Drive Cage at Port 2I, Box 3, OK

Internal Drive Cage at Port 3I, Box 2, OK

Internal Drive Cage at Port 4I, Box 0, OK

Port Name: 1I (Mixed)

Port Name: 2I (Mixed)

Port Name: 3I (Mixed)

Port Name: 4I (Mixed)

Array A (Solid State SATA, Unused Space: 619995  MB)

```
  logicaldrive 1 (13.35 TB, RAID 5, OK)
  logicaldrive 3 (97.66 GB, RAID 5, OK, Encrypted)

  physicaldrive 1I:3:3 (port 1I:box 3:bay 3, SATA SSD, 1.9 TB, OK)
  physicaldrive 1I:3:4 (port 1I:box 3:bay 4, SATA SSD, 1.9 TB, OK)
  physicaldrive 2I:3:5 (port 2I:box 3:bay 5, SATA SSD, 1.9 TB, OK)
  physicaldrive 2I:3:6 (port 2I:box 3:bay 6, SATA SSD, 1.9 TB, OK)
  physicaldrive 2I:3:7 (port 2I:box 3:bay 7, SATA SSD, 1.9 TB, OK)
  physicaldrive 2I:3:8 (port 2I:box 3:bay 8, SATA SSD, 1.9 TB, OK)
  physicaldrive 3I:2:1 (port 3I:box 2:bay 1, SATA SSD, 1.9 TB, OK)
  physicaldrive 3I:2:2 (port 3I:box 2:bay 2, SATA SSD, 1.9 TB, OK)
  physicaldrive 3I:2:3 (port 3I:box 2:bay 3, SATA SSD, 1.9 TB, OK)
```

Array B (Solid State SAS, Unused Space: 0  MB)

```
  logicaldrive 2 (1.46 TB, RAID 1, OK)

  physicaldrive 1I:3:1 (port 1I:box 3:bay 1, SAS SSD, 1.6 TB, OK)
  physicaldrive 1I:3:2 (port 1I:box 3:bay 2, SAS SSD, 1.6 TB, OK)
```

Unassigned

```
  physicaldrive 3I:2:4 (port 3I:box 2:bay 4, SATA SSD, 1.9 TB, OK)
```

SEP (Vendor ID HPE, Model Smart Adapter) 379  (WWID: 51402EC0101930C0, Port:                                                                                                                                Unknown)

**esxcli ssacli cmd -q "ctrl slot=0 array A show detail**

HPE Smart Array P816i-a SR Gen10 in Slot 0 (Embedded)

Array: A

```
  Interface Type: Solid State SATA

  Unused Space: 619995 MB (3.76%)

  Used Space: 15.13 TB (96.24%)

  Status: OK

  MultiDomain Status: OK

  Array Type: Data

  Smart Path: disable
```

**esxcli ssacli cmd -q "ctrl slot=0 ld 1 show detail"**

HPE Smart Array P816i-a SR Gen10 in Slot 0 (Embedded)

Array A

```
  Logical Drive: 1
     Size: 13.35 TB
     Fault Tolerance: 5
     Heads: 255
     Sectors Per Track: 32
     Cylinders: 65535
     Strip Size: 256 KB
     Full Stripe Size: 2048 KB
     Status: OK
     Unrecoverable Media Errors: None
     MultiDomain Status: OK
     Caching:  Enabled
     Parity Initialization Status: Initialization Completed
     Unique Identifier: 600508B1001CF5292D04E2997538B8A5
     Logical Drive Label: 011F40B6PEYHD0BRHAM071 8E13
     Drive Type: Data
     LD Acceleration Method: Controller Cache
     Encryption: Off
```

**esxcli ssacli cmd -q "ctrl slot=0 show detail"**

HPE Smart Array P816i-a SR Gen10 in Slot 0 (Embedded)

Encryption is enabled for this controller. Data stored on physical drives that
are exposed to the OS will not be encrypted.

Bus Interface: PCI

Slot: 0

Serial Number: PEYHD0BRHAM071

RAID 6 (ADG) Status: Enabled

Controller Status: OK

Hardware Revision: A

Firmware Version: 1.34-0

Rebuild Priority: High

Expand Priority: Medium

Surface Scan Delay: 3 secs

Surface Scan Mode: Idle

Parallel Surface Scan Supported: Yes

Current Parallel Surface Scan Count: 1

Max Parallel Surface Scan Count: 16

Queue Depth: Automatic

Monitor and Performance Delay: 60  min

Elevator Sort: Enabled

Degraded Performance Optimization: Disabled

Inconsistency Repair Policy: Disabled

Write Cache Bypass Threshold Size: 1040 KiB

Wait for Cache Room: Disabled

Surface Analysis Inconsistency Notification: Disabled

Post Prompt Timeout: 15 secs

Cache Board Present: True

Cache Status: OK

Cache Ratio: 20% Read / 80% Write

Drive Write Cache: Disabled

Total Cache Size: 4.0

Total Cache Memory Available: 3.8

No-Battery Write Cache: Disabled

SSD Caching RAID5 WriteBack Enabled: True

SSD Caching Version: 2

Cache Backup Power Source: Batteries

Battery/Capacitor Count: 1

Battery/Capacitor Status: OK

SATA NCQ Supported: True

Spare Activation Mode: Activate on physical drive failure (default)

Controller Temperature (C): 50

Capacitor Temperature  (C): 40

Number of Ports: 4 Internal only

Encryption: Enabled

Express Local Encryption: False

Encryption Login Status: Not Logged In

Encryption Allow Plaintext Volumes: Allow

Encryption Key Management Mode: Local Key Management Mode

Encryption Supported: True

Encryption RTC SRAM Status: Passed

Encryption Master Key reset in Progress: False

Encryption Local Key Cache Enabled: False

Encryption Crypto Officer Password: Set

Encryption User Password: Set

Encryption FW Locked for Update: Unlocked

Encryption Physical Drive Count: 9

Encryption Controller Password: Not Set

Encryption Local Key Cache Supported: False

Encryption Controller Locked: Unlocked

Encryption Has Suspended Controller Password: False

Encryption Controller Password Unlock Attempts Remaining: 0

Encryption Logical Drive(s) Locked For Missing Controller Password: False

Encryption Password Recovery Parameters Set: False

Encryption Master Key: Set

Encryption Remote Mode Master Key Mismatch: False

Encryption/SSD Smart Path Mixing Supported: True

Encryption/SSD Cache Mixing Supported: True

Encryption Skip Controller Password Enabled: False

PMS Running: False

Driver Name: smartpqi

Driver Version: VMware  1.0.1.244

PCI Address (Domain:Bus:Device.Function): 0000:5C:00.0

Negotiated PCIe Data Rate: PCIe 3.0 x8 (7880 MB/s)

Controller Mode: Mixed

Port Max Phy Rate Limiting Supported: False

Latency Scheduler Setting: Disabled

Current Power Mode: MaxPerformance

Survival Mode: Enabled

Host Serial Number: 2M281702JC

Sanitize Erase Supported: True

Sanitize Lock: None

Sensor ID: 0

```
  Location: Capacitor

  Current Value (C): 40

  Max Value Since Power On: 49
```

Sensor ID: 1

```
  Location: ASIC

  Current Value (C): 50

  Max Value Since Power On: 61
```

Sensor ID: 2

```
  Location: Unknown

  Current Value (C): 42

  Max Value Since Power On: 53
```

Primary Boot Volume: None

Secondary Boot Volume: None

Comment: Please show the output of `ssacli ctrl all show config` and `ssacli ctrl all show config detail`.

Comment: The fault is irrelevant, you shouldn't be using R5 anyway, it's been a dangerous technology for over a decade now, in fact I personally think it's negligent that manufacturers even offer it these days. Please move off it, R1/10 and R6/60 (and ZRAID if you're into that) are the only games in town.

Comment: I added the config and detailed information for the controller, as well as detail for the array and LD in question.  I had to manually double-space a couple of these as the editor smooshed it together for some reason.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not going to move off RAID 5.  I understand the risks and the exposure after a single-drive failure till the array is rebuilt, and they're acceptable in this case versus the tradeoffs in cost and performance.  Please focus on the question and don't hijack my thread.

Comment: It's not that Martin - it's the almost guaranteed damage to your data with every disk rebuilt - I'm also not hijacking your 'thread' (it's not a forum), I'm one of the longest standing and highest-awarded question-answerers on this site and I was trying to help as we get someone on this site at least once a month who has lost all their data due to using R5.

Comment: Okay, sorry.  I've had to do about 7 or 8 rebuilds over the last 16 years with my 25 DL380s housing from 8 to 25 drives each.  I hadn't noticed any data damage, didn't realize there might be any, but will now do research.  When I started in computing in 1974 my storage was ticker tape, then punch and mark sense cards.  I still remember a whole box of cards squirting out from under my arm and cards lying all over the pavement with my O/S on it.  I managed to recover it, so RAID 5 seems okay to me.  But in the meantime I'd really like to know why I can't extend my Logical Drive.

Comment: I started about then too :) Have you got Smart Cache enabled with this at all?

Comment: No.  I get some support from a Managed Service and they said Smart Cache complicates things too much.  The drives in this array are all SATA SSDs, a bit more affordable.  Array B has a couple of SAS SSDs which is used for the Temp Drives of the SQL Servers running on this box.  There are also a couple of NVMe drives that bypass the controller obviously.  Everyone understands these drives have no backup and should only be used for high-speed manipulation of data that is also available somewhere else.  I also have a hot standby for this box and nightly backups.

Comment: RAID5 is fine for the types of drives being used here. RAID6 would be better, though.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the reason I couldn't allocate all of the 619995 MB is that some of that storage is needed for the RAID 5 parity.  I expanded LD 1 to the max allowed and it was allocated 551104 MB as per the amount that SSA told me could be allocated to it, despite showing 619995 MB of unused storage.

Note that 551104/619995 equals 8/9.  Note also that I have 9 drives in a RAID 5 configuration so that is essentially 8 drives of data and one drive for parity.

Hence when SSA reports "Unused Space" that space includes space needed for parity so you won't be able to use all of it for your data.

Also, that means that unused space in the array is available to any LD in the array, which is what you would expect from HP's documentation.  Just don't forget to deduct for parity.

Answer (score 0):

You can't expand the size of LD1 because LD2 is in the way.
You can create a LD3 in the unused space or delete LD2 and extend LD1.

Comment: Thanks very much, @ewwhite.  In the SSA user guide it says "If the operating system supports logical drive extension, you can use any unassigned capacity on an array to enlarge one or more of the logical drives on the array".  I thought that meant I could expand any of the LDs, but I guess you're saying no, the partition start of LD2 can't change so that sets an upper limit to LD1, and I can only use the remaining space to extend LD2.  Do I understand correctly?  In that case I think the SSA documentation leaves a bit to be desired.

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes, thanks. I gather that LDs start at a fixed position in an array and that sectors can’t be assigned at random to an LD, only contiguously.  So when one LD reaches the starting point of another that’s all the space that can be allocated unless the other is deleted. I wish the HP documentation had explained it better, and thank you again for clarifying.